# Modify row height in xslfo

Tags: java, xml, xsl-fo

I have a PDF generated using xslfo.  In that, I have a table that has a row where one cell spans over two rows cells.  Among the two row cells it spans, I need the lower cell to be of smaller height and I tried a few things that did not work.  Here is the code- any help will be appreciated.

```
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" padding="1pt" display-align="before" number-rows-spanned="3">
<fo:block wrap-option="wrap" text-align="left">
<xsl:value-of select="$TextStrings/NSEF21B/Scope_Ins_Cov_Heading1"/>
</fo:block>
<fo:block wrap-option="wrap" text-align="left">
<xsl:value-of select="$TextStrings/NSEF21B/Scope_Ins_Cov_Heading1b"/></fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center">
<fo:block wrap-option="wrap" text-align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="$TextStrings/NSEF21B/Scope_Ins_Cov_Heading2"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" padding="1pt" display-align="center">
<fo:block wrap-option="wrap" text-align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="$TextStrings/NSEF21B/Scope_Ins_Cov_Heading3"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
<fo:table-row>
<fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" padding="1pt" display-align="before">
<fo:block text-align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="$TextStrings/Deductible"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
<fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" padding="1pt" display-align="before">
<fo:block text-align="center">
<xsl:value-of select="$TextStrings/AsStatedSecB"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since this is still unanswered:

Setting [the height attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/prop_height.asp) on your `<fo:table-row>` elements should do the trick.